# How to pack a Rust enum into its minimal size?

Tags: rust, enums, abi, memory-layout

I have a Rust enum with some data. I want to pack it into as few bytes as possible. I tried using `repr` like this:

```rust
#[repr(u8)]
enum MyEnum {
    OptionA(u32),
    OptionB(u32),
    Nothing,
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", std::mem::size_of::<MyEnum>()); // prints 8 (should be 5)
}
```

In theory, this should only need to take up 5 bytes (1 for a `u8` discriminant and 4 for the `u32`s). But, regardless of what `repr` I use, it takes up the full 8 bytes, as if it was aligned to 4.

The [official Rust docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/other-reprs.html#repru-repri) make it clear that `repr(u*)` does what you expect for fieldless enums, but the section on enums with fields is ambiguous to me:

> If the enum has fields, the effect is similar to the effect of `repr(C)` in that there is a defined layout of the type. This makes it possible to pass the enum to C code, or access the type's raw representation and directly manipulate its tag and fields.

So the layout is defined, but does the argument to repr just not do anything? Or is this a bug? This seems insane to me. I understand that it is often more performant to align fields, but what is the point of letting you specify a repr if it does nothing? If I want memory-efficient packing to I have to implement it myself and lose all of rusts pattern matching and safety guarantees?

Comment: Curious what your reason for wanting it is? Memory is 8bit aligned as that is more optimal for CPUs - it's better to have a gap than pack it with something else

Comment: @Dominic I'm working on 8-bit embedded hardware. Alignment has no effect on this architecture and memory is extremely precious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, this type has to be 8 bytes.  That's because it contains a `u32`, which is 4 bytes and must be aligned to a 4-byte address, and if you have an array, then the elements of the array must each be aligned to a multiple of 4 bytes, which requires that the size be a multiple of 4.  Otherwise, you could take a mut reference to the object which would not be aligned, and references are not allowed to be unaligned.

Unaligned access is always slower, and on some architectures it also kills the process with a `SIGBUS`.  Some architectures that would normally have your process killed can have the kernel fix up the access at the enormous cost of a trap, a context switch into the kernel, two loads and some shifts, and then a context switch out of the kernel.  Usually people on those architectures prefer the `SIGBUS` instead because then at least the problem is obvious.  Even RISC-V, one of the newest architectures, doesn't guarantee fast unaligned access (it may trap into the kernel).

Note that the C compiler does the same thing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

struct foo {
    uint8_t tag;
    uint32_t value;
};

int main(void)
{
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(struct foo));
}
```

That prints 8.  It is true that some C compilers offer packed representations, but they are nonstandard.

There has been some discussion of packed enums in Rust, but they have not been standardized yet, and so are not available.

Comment: Ok, so it sounds like there is basically no way to pack an enum. I understand that you probably wouldn't ever want that on 64-bit architecture, but on 8-bit architecture it is very important. I'll keep an eye on the discussions and hopefully it gets added some day.

Comment: "Unaligned access is always slower" => Citation needed? If I recall correctly, on modern x64, there's no penalty for unaligned access, though only certain instructions support them.

Comment: It's important to note that the size _need not_ (at assembly level) be a multiple of the alignment. AFAIK, Swift is the only mainstream language to differentiate between the _size_ (number of bytes) and the _stride_ (spacing between array elements). In Swift, this enum would have an alignment of 4 bytes, a size of 5 bytes, and a stride of 8 bytes. Most notably, this means that if placed in a `struct`, it would be possible to place 3 more bytes of data next to it...

Comment: ... it was considered to do so in Rust as well, but ultimately decided against as there was already significant amount of `unsafe` code which assumed that size equaled stride.

Answer (score 3):

As [documented](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/other-reprs.html#repru-repri) `#[repr(u8)]` has 2 effects on an enum with fields:

1. > there is a defined layout of the type. This makes it possible to pass the enum to C code, or access the type's raw representation and directly manipulate its tag and fields.
2. > If the discriminant overflows the integer it has to fit in, it will produce a compile-time error

So it definitely does something. Though the [`#[repr(packed)]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/other-reprs.html#reprpacked) that you seem to be after does not currently work on enums.

It is a *very* nieche repr anyways and comes with serious drawbacks and the documentation even states it

> is not to be used lightly. Unless you have extreme requirements, this should not be used.

Should you despite all the warnings and probably about 0 benefits still want to do this you can use a manually tagged union:

```rust
#[repr(u8)]
enum Discriminant {
    OptionA,
    OptionB,
    Nothing,
}
union Payload {
    value: u32,
    nothing: (),
}
#[repr(packed)]
struct MyEnum {
    discriminant: Discriminant,
    payload: Payload,
}
```

You can even match on it, but creating a reference to the `payload` is UB (as references have to be aligned), so to read from it you have to use [`read_unaligned`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/fn.read_unaligned.html) but that's true for any `packed` datastructure so `unsafe` is unavoidable to begin with (and not something brought in only for the `union` access).